# ftp: connect : Connection refused error in Debian

Tags: debian, ftp

I'm new to virtual machines. I'm trying to connect metaploistable machine from debian machine through ftp. But my Debian machine is refusing to connect.

The following image shows the commands typed in metaploistable machine to confirm whether ftp server is running on it.

`sudo netstat -pnlt : grep 21 > netstatResults.txt
grep -r "21" netstatResults.txt
ifconfig`

[image]

The following image shows the output of Debian machine after typing the following command.

```
ftp 10.0.2.4
```

[image]

can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: @AlexStragies Thank you for your suggestions. But when i tried to connect metaploistable machine from kali machine, it's working fine. So the problem might be in debian.  Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: @AlexStragies `ping` is working in both ways. and `nmap` is also working. In which machine I need to type `netstat -tnlp | grep 21`? (I couldn't copy paste commands.)

Comment: @AlexStragies Isn't there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: There surely is a way to fix this. `netstat -tnlp` shows listening tcp processes. As such, it needs to be run on the ftp-server to confirm whether it is running (and on the correct port). You could have gleaned that by reading the netstat manual. `nmap` can be used to test, whether ports on one machine are reachable from the other, and it can do more. Again, read the manual, then use e.g. nmap then to probe for open ports connected to ftp, or all. Then you know for sure, that the ftp-server a) runs, b) is reachable from the client, c) not firewalled. Then you confirm those findings in an edit.

Comment: also, you might want to confirm, that you understood, what i meant about `:` vs. `|` by updating the screenshots with correct commands&output. Or better, connect to your VM from a terminal, from which you can SSH (and therefore Copy&Paste&Post the output).

Answer (score 1):

You are using NAT, you need to set the port forwarding from the VirtualBox settings or through the following command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "metasploitable" --natpf1 "FTP,tcp,127.0.0.1,50000,10.0.2.4,21"
```

then connect:

```
ftp 127.0.0.1 50000
```